# calling image by id in html, image not showing

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to call the path of an of an image which is being dynamically called and stored using php and javascript. I am not sure if the id tag work with using an image. The syntax below results the image not being displayed, even though i know for sure an image exists.

```
<img src="browse/level1/images/subcategory/" + id ="myimage1" + "1_1.jpg">
```

myimage1 is part of a path, specific to an item you click on, it is not an image

The data is coming from a html data- element in a while loop depending on which button is clicked.

```
data-id-myimage1="<?php echo $product['ProductImage1'];?>
```

Then added to a function for when the button is clicked.

```
  $("#myimage1").text($(this).attr('data-id-myimage1'));
```

Comment: Why concatenate with `+` the element ? Do you use JS to create the element or PHP ? Put the full code..

Comment: The + makes your HTML invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from what you've written that `myimage1` is a javascript variable.

You could store it into a php variable and then use it within the `<img/>` tag like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $tmp_id = "<script>document.write(myimage1)</script>"?>   
</script>

<img src="browse/level1/images/subcategory/" + <?php echo $tmp_id ?> + "/1_1.jpg">
```